# Accessing enemies' locations quickly in a 2D game

Tags: design-patterns, performance

I have a simple 2D game which has squares, player (teal) and enemies (red).

[image: my game]

```
class Game {
  List<List<Square>> map;
  Player player;
  List<Enemy> enemies; ...
```

My problem is that I don't know what would be the best way to store the coordinates (int x, int y) of the enemies. Currently each enemy contains their coordinates.

```
class Enemy {
  int x;
  int y; ...
```

If I want to check if a square (map[x][y]) contains an enemy, I have to go through all the enemies in the list. This is not good because checking if a  square contains an enemy is done often in the game. I could try to use a `Map<Coordinate, Enemy> enemies` where the key is the coordinate of the enemy, but then the coordinate would be stored in two places and this could create some annoying bugs.

How should I organize the code so that I can easily and quickly access the enemy's coordinates and check if a square contains an enemy? Is it a bad idea to keep the enemy location in the enemy class? Any architectural/design patterns that could help me?

Comment: "I have to go through all the enemies in the list." - maybe articulate what the problem is with that before continuing down the rabbit hole.

Comment: It's done often in the game and the performance of looping through list is O(n). The point of the map would be to make this process faster O(1).

Comment: I see you falling into the trap of premature optimization. 1) you also have to maintain your data structures and include the cost of that housekeeping in your O() analysis, which makes the comparison murkey, and 2) also for small inputs the constant factors ignored in O() can make it break which is faster. You should be focusing on correctness and data modelling moreso at this stage.

Comment: Not in this case. Finding if a square contains an enemy is done often. There can be 1 000s of enemies and 1 000 000s of squares. I know that often people do premature optimization but in this case it really matters.

Comment: @MaLa Calling something premature doesn't mean the same as calling it unnecessary. You're just focusing on it at the wrong point in time. Get it right, before you get it optimized. Your optimizations are going to be bad and/or requiring significantly more effort if you jump the gun.

Comment: 1 000s of enemies are not really a lot. You say 'often', but how frequently is that? A few times per frames? or once per enemy? Once per square? Have you done any measurements?

Comment: Sidenote: Consider `Map<Region, Enemy>`, and then iterate over the enemies in the 4 closest regions. Then you don't have to iterate over all of the `Coordinates` that the user can see

Comment: @Flater what you're describing here is more of an example of recommending premature _pessimisation_ than recommending against premature optimisation. "brute forcing" object interactions by pairs is _obviously_ a terrible idea when there's a nontrivial number of possible pairs. "Avoid premature optimisation" doesn't mean "stop thinking".

Comment: @Cubic: OP mentions that they "don't know what would be the best way to store the coordinates". That comes _before_ optimization, as different approaches can be optimized differently. Based on the posted code, I'd say it is significantly more pertinent to refactor the individual `x`/`y` fields into some sort of `Point`-like structure and consider how you want to compare them for equality. Afterwards, you can then start considering how to store these structures for optimized lookup.

Comment: When you have further questions that are about game development, then you might want to consider asking them on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com. You will get answers and more importantly votes on said answers from people who have game development experience and know how such problems are usually solved in game development. The community here on software engineering SE are mostly application developers.

Comment: @Flater how to store the coordinates is pretty pertinent to optimisation, because how you lay out your data is a pretty core component in what algorithms can be applied. They're not issues that can be addressed sequentially, they're deeply linked.

Comment: Not the greatest color choices for the segment of the population that is colorblind.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For this kind of domain, it is is not uncommon that you need bidirectional lookup:

- quick access to the coordinate of an enemy (or more general, of any kind of piece)
- quickly determine which piece is placed on a given coordinate.

Hence, your idea of using an additional map (together with storing the coordinate pair inside the enemy) is fine. What you need to make sure is that there will be only one place in your code which is allowed to change the coordinates of a piece, and this code updates always both in sync, the coordinate of the piece and the map content. That will help to keep the redundancy under control and avoid the kind of "annoying bugs" you mentioned.

Of course, what others wrote about moving the coordinates out of the `enemy` class is also possible. Though it does not solve the described problem directly, it can help to make the implementation of the coordinate change in one place more rigid.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like my issue is not that the data will be stored in two places but that it can be changed in too many ways.

Comment: @MaLa: One way to ensure this would be to remove the location information from the enemy class and have two maps instead, one mapping locations to things and one mapping things to locations. These maps, however, would be private fields of a class which only exposes public `getThingAtLocation`, `getLocationOfThing` and `setLocationOfThing` methods. It can only expose other helpful methods (e.g. `iterateThroughLocationsForDrawing`), but the important part is that modifications can only be done through its methods, not directly in the maps.

Comment: @Heinzi: yes, that class could be the board or game class itself, or it could be a class `EnemyPositions`, which encapsulates the bidirectional lookup.

Comment: this doesn't really help. you just change the problem from loop through all enemies, to loop through all the squares the player can see. Instead divide the map into square zones the size of your view range, Map.Zones, where each Zone contains a list of enemies in that Zone. then you can limit your search to the squares that overlap your view distance and loop through the enemies in each of those rather than all of them

Comment: @Ewan: where in this post did you find the requirement to "find all enemies the player can see" in the question? It was  *"I want to check if a square (map[x][y]) contains an enemy"*.

Comment: Even if you need to extend to fetch "all enemies you can see", having them indexed by zone/grid square is a reasonable start.

Comment: @DocBrown is a common issue in any game and there are some established patterns to deal with it.

Answer (score 18):

While there is potentially some question as to whether you need it, there is a well-known and fairly easy approach to structuring data so that you can quickly determine if a region contains something and reduce the time complexity around location-based searches.  In the case of a 2-D space the data structure is called a [Quad Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).  If you are familiar with binary trees, it's very similar in structure.  The key idea is that each child node represents a subsection of the parent node and contains references to the items in it.

Now, before everyone goes after me for suggesting a premature optimization, let me explain why you might want to use such an approach.  I would wager a guess that at some point, you might need to know if an enemy is near a player, let's say 10 blocks or less.  If you do this naively, that means doing the calculation of distance between the player and every enemy.  Maybe with 1000 enemies, that might be doable.
Wasteful but doable.  If the number grows or you need to do something like figure out if enemies are near each other, it could become problematic.

With a quad tree, you can very quickly narrow down what enemies are possibly close before accessing their locations.  For example, for the problem above, if you have a quad tree with a minimum size of 10 X 10 blocks, you know that only the block containing the player and directly adjacent blocks could reference enemies within the radius.  It will also optimize the single location lookup as well.

If you go down this route, you should be careful to treat it like a formal collection.  That is, create methods for adding, moving, and finding thing in one place.  Do not try to interact directly with the structure's implementation from various other parts of the code.  Generic advice, yes, but I think it's particularly important in this case.

Comment: If the game has coordinates that go to infinity, can a quad tree still be used?

Comment: @theonlygusti It can. Each of your coordinates is finite, after all.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 how would that work? The first level is "easy": the children of the root can be the Quadrants I, II, III, IV of the xy plane. However, how is further division possible? What would the four children of Quadrant I represent? Or is another model necessary?

Comment: @theonlygusti I think *infinite* coordinates will be difficult, but arbitrary large should be no problem if the tree is *sparse*. The depth of the tree should be `O(log n)` where n is the size of the bounds. So even if you use a long for each coordinate this should work fine. If you are using a double/float you will get into trouble sooner or later due to the varying precision.

Comment: @theonlygusti It's not totally clear to me what 'infinte' coordinates means from a real-world computing perspective but you could use the range from 0 to 1 for each axis and divide them to the limits of the available precision.

Comment: @JimmyJames is it a limitation of quad trees that they need to know the size of the map when they are created? what if the player makes the map bigger? should the infinite game map be divided into lots of smaller quad trees, and stored in a (hash) map of (corner) coordinates to quad trees for that "chunk"?

Comment: @theonlygusti If you need to store something in a coordinate outside the current quad tree, just make the current tree a child node of a bigger tree as required. (You have to keep track of what "scale" you've got, but that's only a single integer; doesn't take up much space, all things considered.) Though I would recommend using a chunking system, in practice, since most games aren't scale-invariant.

Comment: @theonlygusti Along with what wizzwizz4 suggests, you could also keep 'edge' nodes which represent which is unbounded on one or two sides.  A typical approach is to split a given node when it contains more than N entities so you can simply split oof a new fully bounded node from the edge node once you have more than N entities in an edge node.  I think the harder problem is how you represent the coordinates in 'infinite' space given no computer exists that can represent arbitrarily large numbers without losing precision.  That's not specific to this problem, though.

Comment: @DocBrown I see now that you are correct.  I will edit the answer.  It's probably more that it's a common solution that fits exactly what the OP asked for.  So, when I saw the answers, I made a logical leap primed by the comments.

Answer (score 16):

Simple, stop asking things to know where they are. You don’t inherently know where you are. Why should they? The battle field is what holds things. Let it store where things are.

That said, there may be times when something needs to know where it is to do the things it does. Fine, tell it where it is when you tell it to do whatever it’s doing. No need for it to remember.

Done this way you don’t care how many ways there are to move anything. The battle field is the source of truth. You can spread that truth. You can even record what it was. Just remember it’s the battle field that knows.

There may be times when you need to iterate over the enemies without looping the battlefield. If so then you have a real need to maintain current location information outside the battlefield. Understand to store the information in two places at once, in sync, successfully, requires transactions. So be sure you really need this.

Comment: That sounds right. I have think about a way to remove the coordinates from the enemies but also make it so that it's easy to find and move them.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the bi-directional lookup for your use-case, but I would extend it with another solution for huge systems: Split the map into chunks, where each chunk contains a reference list of it's contents. This will also allow for dynamic loading/unloading of map areas, e.g. to disable enemies that are far away, while keeping cheaper comparisons.
This will increase integration effort on the boundaries, but has the potential to scale much larger. Look into infinite world generation (e.g. Minecraft) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

A common technique used in game development to speed up collision detection in large worlds with many entities is [spatial hashing](https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/spatial-hashing-r2697/) (which, despite the name, usually doesn't use any hash algorithms).

The general idea is:

1. You divide the game map into cells
2. Each cell gets a list of entities which currently occupy it
3. When an entity moves across cell borders, you remove it from the list of the old cell and add it to the new one

Now if you want to check for collisions, you only need to check the entities which are in the cells which are overlapped by the collision area.

Note that in many games, entities are not points but occupy a volume. That volume might be partially in cell A and partially in cell B (or even more cells). So it is possible for an entity to be in multiple adjacent cells at the same time.

Now you might wonder: "How large should my cells be exactly?" There is unfortunately no easy answer for that. On the one hand, you want them to be small, so you get fewer entities to check when you do a spatial query. But on the other hand, you don't want them to be *too* small, because then you end up with a whole lot of empty cells which might generate unnecessary overhead and you might end up using a lot of CPU cycles for moving entities between cells. You will have to figure out what cells size works best for your particular game.

Comment: "x + y * 256" is still a hashing algorithm, even if it's really simple. It's not a good _cryptographic_ hash function, but it's a hash. The point of the mechanism is to have an easy way to index into complicated topologies, essentially - the hash function is what allows you to map between the two in a way that is really efficient at handling sparse indices (which is of course the 99% case). Also, while entities do occupy a volume, it's very common to have them discretely be present in one chunk or the other, even if there's overlap.

Comment: @Luaan When you want to use cells for collision detection, then you won't get around to add the object to every cell it touches. Otherwise you don't know which cells to check when looking for collisions. The naive answer would be "I just check the current cell and all the neighbors". But keep in mind that some entities might be so large that they span more than one cell. How would you know in which cells to look if entities like that are potential collision targets?

Comment: Every mechanism has constraints. The common constraint here is that no object is larger than a cell (either as a hard limit, or by splitting a single object into multiple parts for collision detection). Having the object map to all cells that contain it has limits and costs too.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the same idea behind the [Rete algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm). You could make a map that stores the links to the squares that changed. So instead of doing a to down approach, take all the squares then find the ones that changed (an enemy left the square reset the color, an enemy enter the square change the color), you would do a bottom up approach, start from the squares that changed, see what changed.

If the game is turn based it would be very simple. Empty the map at the beginning of the turn, every movement add the squares involved to the map. Finally go through the map.

If the problem is that the main player has a limited field of view and every time it moves it may view enemies that where previously invisible, the story is a bit more complicated, you would have to map all the squares in the surrounding area, but if you can map only the differences in the surrounding areas, before and after moving, it would still be faster than checking all the squares.

If it is a real time engine there would be more work to do, you will have to look into the inference cycles of the algorithm and take inspiration from that mechanism.

Comment: How would that help to "check if a square (map[x][y]) contains an enemy"?

Comment: @Philipp Is it so difficult to understand? By temporary maps I meant lists of key value pairs not the game maps. Every time an enemy moves the link to the position on the game map would be updated in the temporary maps.

Comment: So in order to find out if square 143:67 currently contains an enemy, you would have to iterate all those key-value pairs until you find the last one which sets the value for that square?

Comment: @Philipp Do you know how a map works? You just use the coordinates as key of the map. Then you get the each cell that enters the field of view and check if that key is in the map.

Comment: You wrote "By temporary maps I meant lists of key value pairs not the game maps." And now you say they are maps again? And what do you mean with "map" here anyway? A hashmap? Or a 2-dimensional array? I am sorry, but it is really not clear to me what you actually propose here.

Comment: @Philipp "And now you say they are maps again" Who said that?

Comment: It seems like we are unable to communicate properly. Perhaps someone else can get you to explain this answer.

Comment: @Philipp If you don't understand what is a key value pair it is obvious that we cannot communicate.